# Python unit_test load_tests function failing

Tags: python, python-unittest

Im calling the unittest load_tests to build a test suite but its failing with error.

```
import unittest

def load_tests(loader, tests, pattern):
    print 'load_tests called'
    f = ['a','b']  # data.csv contains three lines: "a\nb\nc"
    for line in f:
        tc = Foo()
        tc.setup(line)
        tests.addTest(tc)
    return tests

class Foo(unittest.TestCase):
    def setup(self,bar):
        print "Foo.setup()"
        print dir(self)
        self.bar = bar


    def runTest(self):
        print 'running'
        print self.bar

unittest.main()
```

Error

```
load_tests called
Foo.setup()
['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_addSkip', '_baseAssertEqual', '_classSetupFailed', '_cleanups', '_deprecate', '_diffThreshold', '_formatMessage', '_getAssertEqualityFunc', '_resultForDoCleanups', '_testMethodDoc', '_testMethodName', '_truncateMessage', '_type_equality_funcs', 'addCleanup', 'addTypeEqualityFunc', 'assertAlmostEqual', 'assertAlmostEquals', 'assertDictContainsSubset', 'assertDictEqual', 'assertEqual', 'assertEquals', 'assertFalse', 'assertGreater', 'assertGreaterEqual', 'assertIn', 'assertIs', 'assertIsInstance', 'assertIsNone', 'assertIsNot', 'assertIsNotNone', 'assertItemsEqual', 'assertLess', 'assertLessEqual', 'assertListEqual', 'assertMultiLineEqual', 'assertNotAlmostEqual', 'assertNotAlmostEquals', 'assertNotEqual', 'assertNotEquals', 'assertNotIn', 'assertNotIsInstance', 'assertNotRegexpMatches', 'assertRaises', 'assertRaisesRegexp', 'assertRegexpMatches', 'assertSequenceEqual', 'assertSetEqual', 'assertTrue', 'assertTupleEqual', 'assert_', 'countTestCases', 'debug', 'defaultTestResult', 'doCleanups', 'fail', 'failIf', 'failIfAlmostEqual', 'failIfEqual', 'failUnless', 'failUnlessAlmostEqual', 'failUnlessEqual', 'failUnlessRaises', 'failureException', 'id', 'longMessage', 'maxDiff', 'run', 'runTest', 'setUp', 'setUpClass', 'setup', 'shortDescription', 'skipTest', 'tearDown', 'tearDownClass']
Foo.setup()
['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_addSkip', '_baseAssertEqual', '_classSetupFailed', '_cleanups', '_deprecate', '_diffThreshold', '_formatMessage', '_getAssertEqualityFunc', '_resultForDoCleanups', '_testMethodDoc', '_testMethodName', '_truncateMessage', '_type_equality_funcs', 'addCleanup', 'addTypeEqualityFunc', 'assertAlmostEqual', 'assertAlmostEquals', 'assertDictContainsSubset', 'assertDictEqual', 'assertEqual', 'assertEquals', 'assertFalse', 'assertGreater', 'assertGreaterEqual', 'assertIn', 'assertIs', 'assertIsInstance', 'assertIsNone', 'assertIsNot', 'assertIsNotNone', 'assertItemsEqual', 'assertLess', 'assertLessEqual', 'assertListEqual', 'assertMultiLineEqual', 'assertNotAlmostEqual', 'assertNotAlmostEquals', 'assertNotEqual', 'assertNotEquals', 'assertNotIn', 'assertNotIsInstance', 'assertNotRegexpMatches', 'assertRaises', 'assertRaisesRegexp', 'assertRegexpMatches', 'assertSequenceEqual', 'assertSetEqual', 'assertTrue', 'assertTupleEqual', 'assert_', 'countTestCases', 'debug', 'defaultTestResult', 'doCleanups', 'fail', 'failIf', 'failIfAlmostEqual', 'failIfEqual', 'failUnless', 'failUnlessAlmostEqual', 'failUnlessEqual', 'failUnlessRaises', 'failureException', 'id', 'longMessage', 'maxDiff', 'run', 'runTest', 'setUp', 'setUpClass', 'setup', 'shortDescription', 'skipTest', 'tearDown', 'tearDownClass']
running
Erunning
a
.running
b
.
======================================================================
ERROR: runTest (__main__.Foo)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 21, in runTest
    print self.bar
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'bar'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.016s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more detailed question would help.  I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve with this code, but I'll try to explain the cause of the error.

The `tests` parameter in your `load_tests` function is a `unittest.TestSuite` object, which already contains one test case.  That test case is a `Foo` object which unittest finds and creates when you call `unittest.main()` because `Foo` is a subclass of `unittest.TestCase`.  You can see this if you `print tests` at the beginning of `load_tests`.

If you only want the two test cases created by load_tests, then load_tests should create and return a new Suite:

```
def load_tests(loader, tests, pattern):
    print 'load_tests called'
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    f = ['a','b']  # data.csv contains three lines: "a\nb\nc"
    for line in f:
        tc = Foo()
        tc.setup(line)
        suite.addTest(tc)
    return suite
```

Output

```
python foo.py 
load_tests called
Foo.setup()
['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_addSkip', '_baseAssertEqual', '_classSetupFailed', '_cleanups', '_deprecate', '_diffThreshold', '_formatMessage', '_getAssertEqualityFunc', '_resultForDoCleanups', '_testMethodDoc', '_testMethodName', '_truncateMessage', '_type_equality_funcs', 'addCleanup', 'addTypeEqualityFunc', 'assertAlmostEqual', 'assertAlmostEquals', 'assertDictContainsSubset', 'assertDictEqual', 'assertEqual', 'assertEquals', 'assertFalse', 'assertGreater', 'assertGreaterEqual', 'assertIn', 'assertIs', 'assertIsInstance', 'assertIsNone', 'assertIsNot', 'assertIsNotNone', 'assertItemsEqual', 'assertLess', 'assertLessEqual', 'assertListEqual', 'assertMultiLineEqual', 'assertNotAlmostEqual', 'assertNotAlmostEquals', 'assertNotEqual', 'assertNotEquals', 'assertNotIn', 'assertNotIsInstance', 'assertNotRegexpMatches', 'assertRaises', 'assertRaisesRegexp', 'assertRegexpMatches', 'assertSequenceEqual', 'assertSetEqual', 'assertTrue', 'assertTupleEqual', 'assert_', 'countTestCases', 'debug', 'defaultTestResult', 'doCleanups', 'fail', 'failIf', 'failIfAlmostEqual', 'failIfEqual', 'failUnless', 'failUnlessAlmostEqual', 'failUnlessEqual', 'failUnlessRaises', 'failureException', 'id', 'longMessage', 'maxDiff', 'run', 'runTest', 'setUp', 'setUpClass', 'setup', 'shortDescription', 'skipTest', 'tearDown', 'tearDownClass']
Foo.setup()
['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_addSkip', '_baseAssertEqual', '_classSetupFailed', '_cleanups', '_deprecate', '_diffThreshold', '_formatMessage', '_getAssertEqualityFunc', '_resultForDoCleanups', '_testMethodDoc', '_testMethodName', '_truncateMessage', '_type_equality_funcs', 'addCleanup', 'addTypeEqualityFunc', 'assertAlmostEqual', 'assertAlmostEquals', 'assertDictContainsSubset', 'assertDictEqual', 'assertEqual', 'assertEquals', 'assertFalse', 'assertGreater', 'assertGreaterEqual', 'assertIn', 'assertIs', 'assertIsInstance', 'assertIsNone', 'assertIsNot', 'assertIsNotNone', 'assertItemsEqual', 'assertLess', 'assertLessEqual', 'assertListEqual', 'assertMultiLineEqual', 'assertNotAlmostEqual', 'assertNotAlmostEquals', 'assertNotEqual', 'assertNotEquals', 'assertNotIn', 'assertNotIsInstance', 'assertNotRegexpMatches', 'assertRaises', 'assertRaisesRegexp', 'assertRegexpMatches', 'assertSequenceEqual', 'assertSetEqual', 'assertTrue', 'assertTupleEqual', 'assert_', 'countTestCases', 'debug', 'defaultTestResult', 'doCleanups', 'fail', 'failIf', 'failIfAlmostEqual', 'failIfEqual', 'failUnless', 'failUnlessAlmostEqual', 'failUnlessEqual', 'failUnlessRaises', 'failureException', 'id', 'longMessage', 'maxDiff', 'run', 'runTest', 'setUp', 'setUpClass', 'setup', 'shortDescription', 'skipTest', 'tearDown', 'tearDownClass']
running
a
.running
b
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```